# Sawtooth Current-Limiter

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, signal-processing

I have a sawtooth waveform passing through two resistors shown in the configuration below.

R200's value is unknown until it gets measured.

I need to adjust the value of R100 to set the peak current value for R200.

So basically some sort of variable resistor that can handle 30 V input.

What circuits can I use to accomplish this? Would a MOSFET operating in the linear region work?

Peak current values are in the range of hundreds of μA.

Y's values range anywhere from 10 kΩ to 100 kΩ.

[image]

Comment: Can R100 be a rheostat?

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the current in R200 at a particular value no matter the value of R200?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set the peak current through R200 no matter what its resistance is. R200 represents the resistance of human skin which can be different depending on a lot of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What circuits can I use to accomplish this?*

You could use a high-side current source fed from your triangle/sawtooth waveform like this: -

[image]

Rsense and the op-amp negative feedback ensure that V2 (the voltage input waveform) is converted to an output current waveform into Rload. So, the voltage across Rsense mimics the input voltage V2 by virtue of negative feedback and op-amp action. Once that is realized then you choose Rsense to deliver the required current or, put another way, you choose Rsense to limit the maximum current.

<sub>There will be some constraints placed on op-amp choice that are typically more rigid compared to negative or ground referenced current sources. The configuration is also inverting and you should take account of this. The circuit can work from a sawtooth input referenced to 0 volts but, the power supply regulation needs to be very good or, an extra op-amp stage will be needed (also used for signal inversion).</sub>

Simulation: -

[image]

Comment: And Vsupply would be 30V in this case?

Comment: It all depends on what the maximum current is needed, the volts lost across Rsense and the BJT (maybe 1 to 2 volts) and the load resistor value @RGBEngineer. Only you know those things.

Comment: Andy, I simulated your solution and it does not work because you can't adjust the current.

Comment: Then you simulated it incorrectly because I have used this circuit dozens of times previously to feed modulated DC current to many multiple loads @RGBEngineer <-- it's a standard circuit i.e. one that does work so please don't say it doesn't. Maybe you chose an unsuitable op-amp?

Comment: how do you adjust the output current then?

Comment: The triangle wave amplitude defines the peak current into the load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139117/discussion-between-rgb-engineer-and-andy-aka).

Comment: @RGBEngineer I left a message in the chat room and you didn't respond. I guess this means you can shut this session down now and select an answer: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve here. If you want to adjust X so that you can get, say 500 μA through Y = 100 kΩ at 30 V input then it's a simple application of Ohm's law.

\$ V_Y = IR = 500\mu \times 100k = 50\ \text V \$

Here you can see that it will not be possible even if X = 0. You'd need 50 V and you've only got 30 V. If you are more specific in your question then there may be a solution for a given range of values.

I think you will get more useful answers if you describe the real problem you are trying to solve rather than working around the solution you've come up with. Why are you using a sawtooth to determine the resistance Y?

Comment: +1 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I am not using a sawtooth to measure the resistance, I am using something else to measure the resistance. The sawtooth is the signal I must current-limit though. I understand that there is a range of useable values. The problem I am trying to solve is I just need to control the peak current of a sawtooth waveform.